# Why all the mails sent using JavaMail API are going to junk folder in outlook

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using javamail API to automate emails in my organization. As per the code I am getting emails but they all are going to junk folder. I tried sending the same content through outlook and it is working fine.
    Please find the code below:-

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
public class MailConfigure {



   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
        new MailConfigure().sendMail();
   }

   public void sendMail()
   {


 String to="";//change accordingly
  //Get the session`enter code here` object
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp server");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");


  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");//change accordingly
   }
  });

  try {
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("my address"));
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
   message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
   message.setSubject("Check this out");
   message.setText("Still not getting result");

      //send message
   Transport.send(message);

  System.out.println("message sent successfully");

  } catch (MessagingException e) 
  {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);}

 }
```

Comment: Post the headers of the message that is accepted, and the message that is marked as junk.

Comment: are you sure you are setting valid email address for from in `message.setFrom` line?

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, try changing up the subject with more capital letters. When I was having my trouble with this the subject really defined for me at least if the mail got sent to the junk folder or not. Like I said try playing around with the subject (more capital letters, less words, more words) and see what happens.